# iOS: What are the Advantages / Disadvantages of using plist or SQLite, as the data source

Tags: ios, sqlite, plist

I am new to cObject or App world, I'm about to make an app where I need to store some information on some players (football), but I do not know where to store them and will hear what you think is best ?

I need to store data like name, age, etc.. I know how I'm doing some text boxes so I can enter the data, but do not know where to save it, I can read that I can use the plist and SQLite, so my quest is if I have about 16-20 names and should only used em on the device where the data have been saved and where I can edit and deleted them, what would you recommend to use as a data source ! or would you recommend another approach ?

Im coding in Xcode atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `CoreDataModel`. `CoreDataModel` is a data storage model for `Objective C`. It's the way faster then `SQL` databases and similar to in terms of creating tables, making table connections. You can find more information in [Ray Wenderlich's Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started).

Since you data model would include many attributes (name, age, etc.), or even relational models I would not suggest using `plists` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

you can use NSUserDefaults if the data you want to store is very small.
Lets say you have an array of users

```
NSArray *users = ,,,,,;
```

to save it

```
[[NSUSerDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:users forKey:@"myKey"];
```

For later to get users data,

```
NSARray *users = [[NSUSerDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```